# Transform literal date parameter to SAS date value in macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to create a SAS macro which takes a literal date (eg. '31may2011'd) as parameter. Inside the macro I want to transform this into a SAS date value (eg. 18778).

```
%macro transLiteralDate2Value(literal=);  
  %put literal = &literal.;  
  %put sasdatavalue = ???;  /* how to calculate this value ? */  
%mend;  
%transLiteralDate2Value(literal='31may2011'd);
```

Is the are elegant way to achieve this? Of course I could do this by parsing the literal string, but I think there must be a better way.

I use SAS 9.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the %sysfunc macro function.

```
%macro transLiteralDate2Value(literal=);  
  %put literal = &literal.;  
  %put sasdatavalue = %sysfunc(putn(&literal.,8.));
%mend;
%transLiteralDate2Value(literal='31may2011'd);
```

Comment: I would also suggest that there is no need to wrap it in a macro call as it is a simple one line statement.

Answer (score 3):

This will work inside or outside of a macro.  Don't forget %sysfunc() has a handy optional second parameter which will let you format the output value.

```
%let report_date = %sysfunc(sum('01JAN2011'd),best.);
```

or

```
%let report_date = %sysfunc(putn('01JAN2011'd,best.));
```

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 2):

It is handy to have a pair of simple conversion macros like mine below. See also [my sas-l posting](http://www.listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1007A&L=sas-l&P=R1001).

```
%macro date2num(date, informat=anydtdte.);
  %*-- strip quotations and postfix d from date literal if any. --*;
  %*-- quotations are intentionally doubled to prevent unmatched error --*;
  %let date=%sysfunc(prxchange(s/[''""]d?//i,-1,&date));
  %sysfunc(inputn(&date,&informat))
%mend  date2num;

%macro num2date(num, format=date10., literal=1);
  %local n;
  %let n = %sysfunc(putn(&num,&format));
  %if &literal %then "&n"d; %else &n;
%mend  num2date;
```

Comment: Or... as I suggested above.  You could just learn to you the %sysfunc and intnx functions.  Macros like these do not help you when you move from job to job or deal with other people's code so I think it's better to avoid them.  Plus if everyone had their own macro wrappers for simple functions you would never be able to remember all of the macro names anyway.